# How to change bookmarks in Firefox shortcuts with right mouse button?

Tags: keyboard, firefox, bookmarks, contextual-menu

If I right click on a bookmark in my shortcuts, there are no options to modify it. Usually in other operating systems, you can change a bookmark with the right mouse button.

(The only way I found out to modify them is via the main menu.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that behaviour was never been implemented in Firefox on OS X.

See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781975).

But you can use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to get to the bookmarks menu and there you can edit all bookmarks by right-clicking.

Answer (score 2):

If you select 'Show All Bookmarks', the Bookmark Library will open.  You can then right-click there and change.

You are quite right in that you cannot right click a menu item in OS X and have it perform a secondary function (not in any of the major browsers anyway).

So the quick way to achieve what you want is - Shift-Command B to bring up the Bookmark Library.

Comment: Thx this helped but its a shame that it is not (yet hopefully) implemented...